# Picking a random name, from a filtered list, based on when that name was last picked

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 2 sheets in it, named "Pickers" and "Names" - This is for a "team picker" for a set of football teams.

The Names sheet has a list of names within it (Column A), their availability (Column B), Date of Last Pick (Column C), and weeks since last pick (Column D) (This also has a function =INT(($F$2-C4)/7) - which is determining how many weeks have lapsed since last picked). See Image.

[Names Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMl3z.png)

In the pickers sheet I have a filter in Column A, which is pulling through names if they are available on any given week `=FILTER(Table2[Names],LEN(Table2[Available?]))`

[Pickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fRYq.png)

In E4 I would like an output of a random name, from this filtered list, based on if there has been 6 or more weeks passed since they last "picked". I can currently get it to output a random name from the filtered list, but if I try to add in any additional criteria I get an error.

I would preferably like it, if this could be done on a button click, but an enter in E4 can also work.

I have also tried an IF function, that tries to look in the "weeks since last pick" column, with a "value if False" as "error" - which always returns "error". Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option, no VBA:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=@SORTBY(FILTER(A2:A16,(B2:B16="Y")*(D2:D16>5),"None"),RANDARRAY(COUNTIFS(B2:B16,"Y",D2:D16,">5")))
```

Or, using `LET()` to store our filtered range first:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A2:A16,(B2:B16="Y")*(D2:D16>5),"None"),@SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(ROWS(x))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough comment. Forgive my ignorance, but I have limited knowledge of the LET function. Is the 'x' a criteria for the filter, whereby I need to add something in there, or is this a part of the function itself?

Comment: It's just a variable that holds the filtered range. The boolean structure in the 2nd parameter of the actual `FILTER()` is where you'd add more criteria @t33ling

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `FILTER` criteria with * to generate list to pick from:

```
=FILTER(RangeToFilter,(Criteria1)*(Criteria2))
```

In example second criteria is `(Today()-Table2[Date of last pick])>42`

Formula:

```
=FILTER(Table2[Names],(Table2[Available?]="Y")*((TODAY()-Table2[Date of last pick])>$F$2))
```

Result:

[image]

Use your formula to calculate *weeks* instead of *days* if needed.